# PHP - Class 'HbaseClient' not found even though it is included

Tags: php, hbase, thrift, thrift-protocol

Been scratching my head for a while on this one.  I'm just getting started with using PHP/Thrift to communicate with HBase (I can do it fine w/Python). For some reason the code below is generating class 'HbaseClient' not found on the $client = new line:

```
$GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = 'thrift';
require_once( $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/Thrift.php' );
require_once( $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/transport/TSocket.php' );
require_once( $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/transport/TBufferedTransport.php' );
require_once( $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php' );
require_once( $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/Hbase/Hbase.php' );

try
{
    $socket = new TSocket('127.0.0.1', 9090);
    $transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
    $protocol = new TBinaryProtocolAccelerated($transport);
    $client = new HbaseClient( $protocol );
    $transport->open();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Exception: %e\r\n";
}
```

I have literally no idea why. In the Hbase.php include file the client is defined as such:

```
class HbaseClient implements \Hbase\HbaseIf {
```

Am I missing something glaringly simple here? (Full HBase.php here: http://pastebin.com/6kd9r2Se )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a namespace issue. Try putting :

```
namespace Hbase;
```

in the file instantiating the object **or** use the fully qualified name:

```
$client = new Hbase\HbaseClient( $protocol );
```

Comment: both work but instead of hijacking their namespace like in the first solution it should be imported: `use Hbase;`

Comment: Thanks I think this is it. What I also realized is I have a version of thrift installed from what I did manually, and from cloudera manager, so I'm thinking I was using the wrong versions of the includes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have placed the HBase folder under THRIFT_ROOT directory or outside?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't that throw a different error if I hadn't (on the require line)?

Comment: have you changed the directory structure of the downloaded package? according to the examples on the thrift with hbase client page the code should be:

`$GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__).'/thrift/src';`

Also, whether the require_once error will be displayed depends on the level of error reporting enabled on your system